# verb 2 vs verb-ing

Tags: grammar

''I could get no further information from Mrs Fairfax about Mr Rochester,but instead she offered to show me round the whole house.
We went through many large,impressive rooms,finally ***reaching*** the top floor,where there was a narrow corridor with several black doors ,all shut''

Jane Eyre_oxford press

İs not the word ''reaching'' supposed to be ''reached'' ??

Comment: The entirety of *finally reaching the top floor,where there was a narrow corridor with several black doors ,all shut* is an [optional] ***adverbial*** element. Syntactically, it's the same as, for example, ***without stopping***, or ***cautiously***. Except my shorter alternatives could reasonably be placed before, within, or immediately after the relevant subject+verb element being modified *(**we went**)*, but it's completely unidiomatic to do that with such a long adverbial clause.

Answer (score 1):

We use the present continuous tense (ending -ing) of a verb to describe a shorter or temporary action that happened during another action, which can be expressed in the simple past, present, or future: I walked in the park, looking at the trees. Charlotte Brontë correctly used this.

[Simple and continuous tenses](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/terrific-tenses-sample-chapter-simple-and-continuous-tenses.pdf)